# Escaped ("\") parentheses used to work fine, but now don't, in <img src=""> path

Tags: html, image, apache, .htaccess, src

So, to try to describe this concisely...

Originally, something like this would work just fine:

```
<img src="/home/adam/public_html/images/Documents \(2014\)/image.png">
```

But, then we did a bunch of upgrades to the server, including PHP version, and I think apache too.

Now, the same `<img>` tag doesn't work, but if I remove the "\"'s before the parentheses, it does work.  So, only this will work now:

```
<img src="/home/adam/public_html/images/Documents (2014)/image.png">
```

There are thousands of documents that all have escaped parentheses, and I'd rather not manually update them all.

I'm wondering who's responsible for interpreting the src="" string in an `<img>` tag, an apache conf file, .htaccess, something else?  I'm guessing there's a setting somewhere that will either allow or disallow escaped parentheses, and I just need to allow it.  I've tried turning magic_quotes off, but that's a php thing, which I'm thinking would never even come into play since `<img>` is just html and not php.  Any thoughts or advice are appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL isn't valid.

You must encode the space and backslashes.

```
<img src="/home/adam/public_html/images/Documents%20%5C(2014%5C)/image.png">
```

For a list of other characters that must be encoded:  http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

This problem at its core doesn't have anything to do with PHP really, but if you want to encode with PHP, use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I'll see if I can implement a function to run any src="" through urlencode() first, sounds like that'll solve my problem.   Thanks again.

Comment: @AdamDeAloe I'm reading your question again and am more confused... why are your parenthesis "escaped" with a backslash?  Parenthesis don't need to be escaped in a URL, and even if they did, a backslash isn't how to do it.  Furthermore, your web server isn't going to modify the output of your application.  Something else is going on here but without seeing any relevant code or knowing the back story, it's hard to be more helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure why they were 'escaped,' it was the previous developer who did that.  What is odd is that, even though they were escaped when they weren't supposed to be, they had been working fine all these years.  It's a Joomla 1.5 website.  I just added a function to str_replace "\(" with "(" and same for \) to ) at the final rendering of the site.  That fixed my problem.  It's a hack, but it only needs to last a few months longer - I got the contract to redo their website.  (oops, stack overflow filtered out my slashes, but you get what I meant)